# Jquery script for a table sliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will need a Jquery script for a table sliding effect just like image :

[image]

Comment: Which image are you talking about?

Comment: That's awesome. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your table inside a div with an id and:

```
$("#yourdivid").animate({
    "marginLeft": "-=100"
},700, function() {

});
```

Maybe it will work with an id on the table...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourtable").slideDown();
```

Here ya go